# Anything like substr but instead of stopping at the byte you specified, it stops at a specific string

Tags: c++, string

I have a client for a pre-existing server. Let's say I get some packets "MC123, 456!@#".

I store these packets in a char called message. To print out a specific part of them, in this case the numbers part of them, I would do something like "cout << message.substr(3, 7) << endl;".

But what if I receive another message "MC123, 456, 789!@#". "cout << message.substr(3,7)" would only print out "123, 456", whereas I want "123, 456, 789". How would I do this assuming I know that every message ends with "!@#".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct approach is to look for existence / location of the "known termination" string, then take the substring up to (but not including) that substring.

Something like

```
str::string termination = "!@$";
std::size_t position = inputstring.find(termination);
std::string importantBit = message.substr(0, position);
```

You could check the front of the string separately as well. Combining these, you could use regular expressions to make your code more robust, using a regex like

```
 MC([0-9,]+)!@\$
```

This will return the bit between `MC` and `!@$` but only if it consists entirely of numbers and commas. Obviously you can adapt this as needed.

**UPDATE** you asked in your comment how to use the regular expression. Here is a very simple program. Note - this is using C++11: you need to make sure our compiler supports it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main(void) {
      std::string s ("ABC123,456,789!@$");
      std::smatch m;
      std::regex e ("ABC([0-9,]+)!@\\$");   // matches the kind of pattern you are looking for

      if (std::regex_search (s,m,e)) {
        std::cout << "match[0] = " << m[0] << std::endl;
        std::cout << "match[1] = " << m[1] << std::endl;
      }
}
```

On my Mac, I can compile the above program with

```
clang++ -std=c++0x -stdlib=libc++ match.cpp -o match
```

If instead of just digits and commas you want "anything" in your expression (but it's still got fixed characters in front and behind) you can simply do

```
std::regex e ("ABC(.*)!@\\$");
```

Here, `.+` means "zero or more of 'anything'" - but followed by `!@$`. The double backslash has to be there to "escape" the dollar sign, which has special meaning in regular expressions (it means "the end of the string").

The more accurately your regular expression reflects exactly what you expect, the better you will be able to trap any errors. This is usually a very good thing in programming. "Always check your inputs".

One more thing - I just noticed you mentioned that you might have "more stuff" in your string. This is where using regular expressions quickly becomes the best.  You mentioned a string

```
MC123, 456!@#*USRChester.
```

and wanted to extract `123, 456` and `Chester`. That is - stuff between `MC` and `!@$`, and more stuff after `USR` (if that is even there). Here is the code that shows how that is done:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main(void) {
      std::string s1 ("MC123, 456!@$");
      std::string s2 ("MC123, 456!@$USRChester");
      std::smatch m;
      std::regex e ("MC([0-9, ]+)!@\\$(?:USR)?(.*)$");   // matches the kind of pattern you are looking for

      if (std::regex_search (s1,m,e)) {
        std::cout << "match[0] = " << m[0] << std::endl;
        std::cout << "match[1] = " << m[1] << std::endl;
        std::cout << "match[2] = " << m[2] << std::endl;
      }
      if (std::regex_search (s2,m,e)) {
        std::cout << "match[0] = " << m[0] << std::endl;
        std::cout << "match[1] = " << m[1] << std::endl;
        std::cout << "match[2] = " << m[2] << std::endl;
        if (match[2].length() > 0) {
           std::cout << m[2] << ": " << m[1] << std::endl;
        }
      }

}
```

Output:

```
match[0] = MC123, 456!@$
match[1] = 123, 456
match[2] = 
match[0] = MC123, 456!@$USRChester
match[1] = 123, 456
match[2] = Chester
Chester: 123, 456
```

The matches are:

```
match[0] : "everything in the input string that was consumed by the Regex"
match[1] : "the thing in the first set of parentheses"
match[2] : "The thing in the second set of parentheses"
```

Note the use of the slightly tricky `(?:USR)?` expression. This says "This *might* (that's the `()?` ) be followed by the characters `USR`. If it is, skip them (that's the `?:` part) and match what follows.

As you can see, simply testing whether `m[2]` is empty will tell you whether you have just numbers, or number plus "the thing after the USR".  I hope this gives you an inkling of the power of regular expressions for chomping through strings like yours.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, but how do I adapt that to return the bit between MC and !@$ if it consists of any character? And how exactly do I print it out onto the screen? Just "cout << MC([0-9,]+)!@$" ?

Comment: @user3376098 - I have updated my answer with a small program that shows how to use the regular expression to extract the information you want.

Answer (score 1):

First - Sketch out the indexing.

```
std::string packet1 = "MC123, 456!@#";
//                     0123456789012345678
//                       ^------^ desired text
std::string packet2 = "MC123, 456, 789!@#";
//                     0123456789012345678
//                       ^-----------^ desired text
```

The others answers are ok. If you wish to use std::string find, 
consider rfind and find_first_not_of, as in the following code:

```
// forward
void messageShow(std::string packet,
                 size_t      startIndx = 2);

// /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main (int, char** )
{
   //           012345678901234567    
   //             |
   messageShow("MC123, 456!@#");
   messageShow("MC123, 456, 789!@#");
   messageShow("MC123, 456, 789, 987, 654!@#");

   // error test cases
   messageShow("MC123, 456, 789#@!"); // missing !@#
   messageShow("MC123x 456, 789!@#"); // extraneous char in packet

   return(0);
}


void messageShow(std::string packet,
                 size_t      startIndx) // default value 2
{
   static size_t seq = 0;
   seq += 1;

   std::cout << packet.size() << "   packet" << seq << ": '" 
             << packet << "'" << std::endl;

   do
   {
      size_t bangAtPound_Indx = packet.rfind("!@#");

      if(bangAtPound_Indx == std::string::npos){ // not found, can't do anything more
         std::cerr << "    '!@#' not found in packet " << seq << std::endl;
         break; 
      }          

      size_t printLength = bangAtPound_Indx - startIndx; 

      const std::string DIGIT_SPACE = "0123456789, ";

      size_t allDigitSpace = packet.find_first_not_of(DIGIT_SPACE, startIndx);

      if(allDigitSpace != bangAtPound_Indx) {
         std::cerr << "    extraneous char found in packet " << seq << std::endl;
         break;    // something extraneous in string
      }

      std::cout << bangAtPound_Indx << "  message" << seq << ":   '"
                << packet.substr(startIndx, printLength) << "'" << std::endl;

   }while(0);

   std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

This outputs

```
13   packet1: 'MC123, 456!@#'
10  message1:   '123, 456'

18   packet2: 'MC123, 456, 789!@#'
15  message2:   '123, 456, 789'

28   packet3: 'MC123, 456, 789, 987, 654!@#'
25  message3:   '123, 456, 789, 987, 654'

18   packet4: 'MC123, 456, 789#@!'
    '!@#' not found in packet 4

18   packet5: 'MC123x 456, 789!@#'
    extraneous char found in packet 5
```

---

Note: String indexes start at 0.  The index of the digit '1' is 2.

Comment: good idea to suggest using `rfind`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about the ending of the message, `message.substr(3, message.size()-6)` will do the trick.

However, it is good practice to check everything, just to avoid surprises.
Something like this:

```
if (message.size() < 6)
    throw error;
if (message.substr(0,3) != "MCX") //the exact numbers do not match in your example, but you get the point...
    throw error;
if (message.substr(message.size()-3) != "!@#")
    throw error;
string data = message.substr(3, message.size()-6);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just calculate the offset first.

```
string str = ...;
size_t start = 3;
size_t end = str.find("!@#");
assert(end != string::npos);
return str.substr(start, end - start);
```

Comment: now what if for example there were more characters after the "!@#", these characters represented the username of the person who sent the packet. For example: MC123, 456!@#*USRChester.   The only things I want to appear on the screen are "Chester" and the message 123, 456. Preferably in this format: "Chester: 123, 456". Thanks~

Comment: I think you may want to look for C++ tutorials.  This isn't the right forum to ask for people to write code for you.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the index of "!@#" by using:

```
message.find("!@#")
```

Then use that answer instead of `7`.  You should also check for it equalling `std::string::npos` which indicates that the substring was not found, and take some different action.

Answer (score 0):

```
    string msg = "MC4,512,541,3123!@#";
for (int i = 2; i < msg.length() - 3; i++) {
    if (msg[i] != '!' && msg[i + 1] != '@' && msg[i + 2] != '#')
        cout << msg[i];
}
```

or use char[]

```
    char msg[] = "MC4,123,54!@#";
sizeof(msg -1 ); //instead of msg.length() 
// -1 for the null byte at the end (each char takes 1 byte so the size -1 == number of chars)
```

Comment: Also, try and add a little explanation to your code. So readers get it on the go. :)